# Changing function from position gives 'name is not declared'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, function, runatserver

I'm working on a project in asp.net with vb.net

I changed a function from team.aspx.vb to a global file with all my functions in it. But now it has some errors (name 'ddl_type' is not declared).
This error makes sense cause this ddl_type had a runat=server and was directly connected to the frontend file team.aspx.

How can I link this ddl_type in my functions.aspx.vb file to the correct id='ddl_type' in my frontend file team.aspx?

Don't really think adding code to this question makes it any clearer?

Comment: It's really best if you provide some code to accompany your question. The odds are that you are trying to access something that is not accessible in it's current context.

Comment: Pass it as parameter... If this function is used only for one dropdown, then I don't see a reason to put it in the global file.

Comment: Just a parameter 'Byval ddl as string' or is there a better option?

Comment: Private Sub fillPFileRelationTypes(byVal dd As DropDownList)